# Difference of "zu X" and "nach X"

Tags: word-usage, difference, usage

I'm having trouble with the difference between those two words ... I read a related topic here that asked the same thing, and the answer was:

> - "Nach Hause gehen" means "to go home" and "zu Hause" means "at home".
>     "Zu" is for location and "nach" for destination. -

But it didn't really worked for me ... I mean, if I wan't to go somewhere, I have a destination/location, isn't it the same thing?!?

And "zu Hause" does translate to "at home", but if I put it in the way as it is below, it translates normally to "I want to go home" ?!

For example:

> "Ich will nach Hause gehen" X "Ich will zu Hause gehen"
>
> "Ich gehe nach Schule" X "Ich gehe zur Schule"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

## **Nach**

1. Countries and Cities

   - Ich fahre nach Berlin  *(I go to Berlin)*
   - Ich fliege nach England  *(I fly to England)*

     **Exception:** Countries that take an article.
   - Ich fliege in die Türkei / die Schweiz / den Jemen / den Kongo *(I fly to Turkey / Switzerland / Yemen / Congo)*
2. Cardinal directions and left/right/up/down

   - Du musst weiter nach Norden! *(You have to go further north)*
   - Geh erst nach links, dann nach oben. *(First go left, then up)*

## **Zu**

1. Persons and companies

   - Peter fährt zu Stefan. *(Peter goes to Stefan's)*
   - Klaus fährt zu Aldi.  *(Klaus goes to Aldi)*
   - Ich fahre zu meiner Mutter. *(I go to my mum)*
2. Replacing auf/in/an

   - Ich fahre an den Strand -> Ich fahre zum Strand  *(I go to the beach)*
   - Wir gehen in die Kneipe -> Wir gehen zur Kneipe *(We go to the pub)*
   - Stefanie geht später auf eine Party -> Stefanie geht später zu einer Party (*Stefanie goes to a party later)*

   **Note:** Replacing *in* with *zu* slightly changes the meaning. Instead of going into the pub, you now just go to the pub i.e. you might just meet outside and go elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Your rule of thumb that *zu* would refer to a location, is wrong.

*zu Hause* means *at home*, but this is the exception and you derive your rule from an exceptional case - which leads to wrong results. To the contrary, in the prototypic case, *zu* is indicating a direction (nowadays).

The use of *zu* to indicate a location is rather exceptional nowadays, but seems to have been normal in earlier times. Besides *zu Hause*, other remains of this can be found in the names of some instituions, where it indicates the location, such as:

- *Gewandhaus zu Leipzig*
- *Universität zu Köln*

and in nobility predicates such as *Karl-Theodor zu Guttenberg*, where *zu Guttenberg* indicates that the dynasty is located or rooted (I am not familiar with the nobility predicates) at *Gutttenberg*.

Just as a very side note: It seems to me as if english *at* has made a similar change just in the other direction, since it stems from Latin *ad* which means *to* and also indicates a direction. So maybe the differentiation between direction and location has not always been very stable.